# Output all column names where the value matches a specific number in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a data frame about whether a patient meets the study criteria, and each row is a patient, each column is a criterion. So some columns are inclusion criteria and some columns are exclusion criteria, and I want to output the reasons for ineligibility. For example,

```
test <- data.frame(A = c(0, 0, 1), 
                   B = c(0, 0, 0), 
                   C = c(0, 1, 1), 
                   D = c(1, 0, 0), 
                   E = c(1, 0, 1))
```

where A, B, C are inclusion criteria and D, E are exclusion criteria, and I want to output the column names (could be more than one) if the inclusion criteria == 0 or exclusion criteria == 1.

The expected output would be

```
output <- data.frame(A = c(0, 0, 1), 
                       B = c(0, 0, 0), 
                       C = c(0, 1, 1), 
                       D = c(1, 0, 0), 
                       E = c(1, 0, 1),
                       failed_incl = c("A, B, C", "A, B", "B"),
                       failed_excl = c("D, E", "", "E"))
```

Is there a way to do it efficiently without having to write out every possible scenario? The actual data frame has much more columns.

Comment: Yeah I just edited it to include the expected output. Thank you!

Comment: updated the  answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiply ways.  An option is to use `apply` to loop over the rows (`MARGIN = 1`), get the `names` of the logical vector (`x== 0`) and `paste` them together

```
test$failed_incl <- apply(test[1:3], 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x == 0]))
test$failed_excl <- apply(test[4:5], 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x == 1]))
```

-output

```
test
#  A B C D E failed_incl failed_excl
#1 0 0 0 1 1     A, B, C        D, E
#2 0 0 1 0 0        A, B            
#3 1 0 1 0 1           B           E
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(failed_incl = toString(names(.)[which(c_across(A:C) == 0)]),
           failed_excl = toString(c('D', 'E')[which(c_across(D:E) == 1)])) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#      A     B     C     D     E failed_incl failed_excl
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>      
#1     0     0     0     1     1 A, B, C     "D, E"     
#2     0     0     1     0     0 A, B        ""         
#3     1     0     1     0     1 B           "E"
```

Comment: Ah my question is a bit different. I want some columns to be 0 and some to be 1, and output all columns that match this. So max.col doesn't work here.

Comment: @KarenLiu it is a lambda function i.e. `function(x)` where the 'x' is the value of each row as we used `MARGIN = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse approach, which pivots the column names and then summarizes based on the inclusion/exclusion conditions:

```r
failed_df <-
  test %>%
  add_rownames() %>%
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>%
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  summarise(failed_incl = paste(name[value == 0 & name %in% c("A", "B", "C")], collapse = ", "),
            failed_excl = paste(name[value == 1 & name %in% c("D", "E")], collapse = ", ")) %>%
  select(-rowname)

bind_cols(test, failed_df)

  A B C D E failed_incl failed_excl
1 0 0 0 1 1     A, B, C        D, E
2 0 0 1 0 0        A, B            
3 1 0 1 0 1           B           E
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this with `rowwise` and `c_across`.